# Laravel 8.55 and queue behavior using S3 file upload

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, queue

I inherited some Laravel code (currently running version 8.55) and there is a job that is initiated by uploading a CSV file via a web page.

That CSV file uploaded to an S3 bucket, processed (using the Laravel-Excel), causing updates to database entries, an email is sent reporting job completion and then the CSV file is deleted from S3.

My development environment is Windows11 (PhpStorm) using MySql and 'php artisan serve' is the webserver that I use.

The queued job works as expected in my local environment.  When attempted in production (hosted on heroku), the file is successfully uploaded to the S3 bucket I'm using and then the following error results (reported in Bugsnag) and the job fails (adding an entry to the failed_jobs table):

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundExceptionMaatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\ReadChunk
File not found at path: laravel-excel-3svOWxojWikYEuWZuBBBHlbXl6WpK7Xb.csv
```

This is an excerpt of the code in the upload script that initiates the job:

```
        $file = $request->file('filename');
        $f_ori_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $file_name = Str::random(40).'.'.$extension;
        $tmp_path = Storage::disk('s3_temp')->put($file_name, file_get_contents($file->getRealPath()));
        $path = Storage::disk('s3_temp')->path($file_name);

        $var = (new MembersImport($currentPerson, $import_detail))->queue($path, 's3_temp')
                        ->chain([
                            new ImportDetailsUpdateJob($import_detail),
                            new NotifyUserOfCompletedImport($currentPerson, $import_detail),
                            function () use ($path) {
                                Storage::disk('s3_temp')->delete($path);
                            }
                        ])->onConnection('database')
                        ->onQueue('default');
```

I'm at a loss given that this works completely locally.

Comment: If everything works in your local as expected, then you have a wrong Key somewhere on your prod environment

Comment: @matiaslauriti interesting thought.  If you're thinking any of the AWS keys, the file is getting uploaded just fine.  Thoughts on which keys to be looking at?  I'll start reviewing all settings shortly.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Turns out that was in fact the problem.  My production environment had all the correct keys but my production queue processing environment (a separate heroku instance) had old AWS keys.  Thank you.

If you want to add that as an "answer" I'd be happy to give you credit.

Comment: No worries! you can add the answer yourself and mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as pointed out by @matiaslauriti, was incorrect AWS keys in one of the environments that was processing the production queue.